# React table search filter work on console window but in react table it not showing filter data

Tags: reactjs

I started learning on reactjs, I have created react table using react semantic UI, whatever code i write it works on console log but in UI not showing filter data

In this arrow function i will see the filter name value using console.log option.
Please check this code below for more understanding.

```
filterList = e => {

}
```

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table, Grid, Header, Button, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class ProjectDashBoardList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        let presets = {
            projectListArray: []
        }
        this.state = {
            filterData: [],
            value: ""
        }
        this.state = presets;
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            filterData: this.state.projectListArray
        });
    };

    filterList = e => {
        const filterDataName = this.state.projectListArray.filter(item => {
            return ( item.customer_name.toLowerCase().search(e.target.value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 );
        });
        this.setState({ filterData: filterDataName });
        console.log('Filter Customer name:', filterDataName);
    };

    render(){
        const filterDataName = this.state.projectListArray            
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <Input icon='search' placeholder='Search by name.' onClick={this.handleChange} onChange={this.filterList} className="searchfield" />
                </form>

                <Table celled selectable >
                    <Table.Header>
                        <Table.Row>
                            <Table.HeaderCell className="headId">Serial No</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Customer</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Project No</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Start Date</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                        </Table.Row>
                    </Table.Header>
                    <Table.Body>
                        { filterDataName.map((item, index) => 
                        <Table.Row key={item.id} className="btnHover">
                            <Table.Cell>{item.id}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell >
                                <Link to={`./customer-details/${item.id}`}>{item.customer_name}</Link>
                            </Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{item.proj_id}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{item.start_date}</Table.Cell> 
                            <Table.Cell>
                                <Button positive onClick={item.skp_snap_url}>Download</Button>
                                <Button negative onClick={this.projectRemove(item)}>Delete</Button>
                            </Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>)}
                    </Table.Body>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to show filter values in table when i will write name in search box.

Comment: Can you provide codepen/sanbox link? That would be helpful

Comment: @nayan-patil you are filtering and setting data to a `state variable` called `filterData`, but in render you are using a different `state variable` ( which is the unfiltered dataset ) `this.state.projectListArray`,

replace 
`const filterDataName = this.state.projectListArray ` 
   with
`const filterDataName = this.state.filterData`

Comment: @Anuja in const filterDataName = this.state.projectListArray i'm fetching values from database  and showing the data in table, if i change this then code is not working. Please check the handleChange arrow function.

Comment: @NayanPatil
just maintain your `unfiltered` all data in your `projectListArray` variable and copy the same to `filterData` variable too, in the beginning, use the `filterData` to render the `<Table.Row/>`s. Filter on `projectListArray` and set it to 'filterData` as you have done.

Comment: @Anuja can you please write in code whatever you tell now so i will get idea on this, I tried as per my understanding but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just maintain your `unfiltered` all data in your `projectListArray` variable and copy the same to `filterData` variable too, in the beginning, use the `filterData` to render the `<Table.Row/>`s. Filter on `projectListArray` and set it to `filterData` as you have done. I don't understand where you `projectListArray` come from, i'll just assume that it comes down from `props` (correct me if i'm wrong, will edit accordingly)

check **`codesandbox`** : https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-boyd-5yqyn?fontsize=14

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Table, Grid, Header, Button, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class ProjectDashBoardList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            filterData: props.projectListArray,
            value: ""
        }
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value,
            filterData : this.filterList(e.target.value)
        });
    };

    filterList = value => {
        return this.props.projectListArray.filter(item => {
            return ( item.customer_name.toLowerCase().search(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1 );
        });
    };

    render(){
        const filterDataName = this.state.filterData            
        return(
            <div>
                <form>
                    <Input icon='search' value={this.state.value} placeholder='Search by name.' onChange={this.handleChange} className="searchfield" />
                </form>

                <Table celled selectable >
                    <Table.Header>
                        <Table.Row>
                            <Table.HeaderCell className="headId">Serial No</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Customer</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Project No</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Start Date</Table.HeaderCell>
                            <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                        </Table.Row>
                    </Table.Header>
                    <Table.Body>
                        { filterDataName.map((item, index) => 
                        <Table.Row key={item.id} className="btnHover">
                            <Table.Cell>{item.id}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell >
                                <Link to={`./customer-details/${item.id}`}>{item.customer_name}</Link>
                            </Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{item.proj_id}</Table.Cell>
                            <Table.Cell>{item.start_date}</Table.Cell> 
                            <Table.Cell>
                                <Button positive onClick={item.skp_snap_url}>Download</Button>
                                <Button negative onClick={this.projectRemove(item)}>Delete</Button>
                            </Table.Cell>
                        </Table.Row>)}
                    </Table.Body>
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: from aws database values i'm stored in projectListArray.

Comment: @NayanPatil added [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-boyd-5yqyn?fontsize=14)

Comment: I tried codesandbox code but it is give me Cannot read property map in undefined.

Comment: @NayanPatil after integrating it to your code or in `codesandbox` itself?

Comment: after integrating in my code or here i have added code in sandbox so please check it, im fetching data from database aws dynamodb table https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-breeze-7g6vh?fontsize=14

Comment: @NayanPatil https://codesandbox.io/embed/eloquent-snowflake-esvp0 , theres a missing credential issue, so the `scan` resolves to an error, add your `AWS credentials` and check.

Comment: Please check the sandbox i have added the credential and in console it is showing data but in UI it not returns any things

Comment: checked still it says `missing credentials` just add you credentials and the code should work

Comment: Check the below link https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-breeze-7g6vh?fontsize=14, Here in console it is showing data.

Comment: @NayanPatil fixed, check, https://codesandbox.io/embed/angry-mccarthy-fylew

the issue was that you cannot use `react-router-dom` `<Link/>` outside a `<Router/>`  and also changed `const filterData = this.state.filterData;` line.

Comment: Thanks you now it is sorted.